# So need I or so do I

Tags: word-choice, semi-modals

What is the correct answer in the second example **need** or **do**?

> A:"I need a holiday."
>
> B:"So need/do I."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Short answer: it's always "so do I" in response to "I need..." - never "so need I".

Long answer:

"Need" is a semi-modal, which means it sometimes acts like a modal and sometimes like a full verb.

You have a free choice between "Need I go on?" and "Do I need to go on?" (the first sounds better to me) and between "Need I pay my taxes?" and "Do I need to pay my taxes?" (the second sounds better unless you are aiming for an elevated style).

However, "I need go on" is barely acceptable (even though "I needn't go on" and "I need hardly go on" work).  So, the modal construction of "need" works in interrogatives and negatives, but is rarely if ever acceptable in positive statements.  For this reason, "so need I" (which is a positive statement) is unacceptable.  ("Neither need I" is acceptable in response to - say - "She needn't go", although it sounds very formal.)

There is a second thing to note, though.  The modal "need" is not used where the object of "need" is a noun (because modals are auxiliaries and therefore need a second verb to govern).  So "I need not a holiday" sounds weird, and "Need I a holiday?" is not something anyone would say in modern English - whereas "I need not go on holiday" and "Need I go on holiday?" are correct (even if the non-modal formulations are more common).  So in "I need a holiday", the verb isn't understood as a modal (both for that reason and because modal "need" is rarely if ever found in positive statements), which again rules out "So need I".

Comment: The question is about the grammar of short answers, not the "semi-modal" nature of "need".

Comment: @gotube I don't agree.  The semi-modal nature of "need" is inherently relevant.  If "need" were a full modal (or if it could be used as a modal in this circumstance) then "So need I" would be correct (cf "So must I", "So shall I", "So ought I", etc).  I had assumed that it was the semi-modality of "need" that prompted the question.

Comment: rjpond, thank you so much for your excellent answer!

Answer (score 2):

In modern English, this kind of construction uses only auxiliary verbs - *So do I; So is he; So should you* and so on.

Comment: Of course, "need" sometimes *is* an auxiliary verb ("I needn't go", "Need I explain?") - although not in the OP's example.